# Confusion with the reasons collector area being greater than the emitter region

Tags: open-collector

Often I come up with the following reasoning when it comes to why collector has larger area than the emitter:

> For less power dissipation collector area should be more. In other
>   words, when area is more, resistance is less for a given current and
>   hence power dissipation is less.
>
> Usually base area < emitter area < collector area

But this argument confuses me because the collector and emitter passes almost the same amount of current. What is the point of saying collector needs to dissipate more power hence it needs to have greater area. If Ic and Ie are almost the same why wouldn't both regions dissipate the same power?

Comment: Indeed, emitter current > collector current. Can you cite that reference. Something may be out of context here.

Comment: emitter current > collector current. Is that the reason? But Ic and Ie are so close to each other. Is that tiny difference have such big impact on the area sizes designated?

Comment: No I was just expanding on what you say. Where did you get the quote form in your question though?

Comment: It was from a discussion forum. http://www.edaboard.com/thread49923.html

Comment: I have a feeling you are misinterpreting the quote. It says it should be more, but not more than what. I think it means the collector and everything else needs to be larger.

Comment: Ok so it only says "all should be large enough" for less power dissipation.

Comment: Yup. especially when you consider the collector is the foundation layer of the transistor that the base and emitter are built on top of. If you make the foundation bigger the whole house gets bigger.

Comment: There are other (more important, probably) good reasons why the collector is larger.

Comment: @jonk What is the biggest two reasons?

Comment: I left this area (I worked on temperature measurement and control systems for FABs) when the transition then was moving somewhat rapidly into 300 mm wafer sizes (today, they are moving [slowly] into 450 mm.) Then, intrinsic silicon wafers were still widely used. Not sure about today, as it appears that doped boules are cheaper than intrinsic silicon (purity costs money now, I guess.) So (1) has to do with the CB depletion region and how best to sweep up carriers and (2) is how these are built and diffuse out in planar processing. Heat generated is also true, as it is related to dopant level.

Comment: The BC junction has to be larger than the area of the BE junction, as this pretty much creates your transistor gain. Carriers injected from E to B may either wind up in the base or the collector. You'd like most of them to get into the BC depletion zone (which means you want a LOT of BC depletion volume) so that they will be swept up into the collector, leaving just enough in the base to maintain the BE biasing. The construction of a planar transistor makes all this pretty much "automatic." (It's easier to understand this when thinking about a photodiode and carriers generated by photons.)

Comment: Anyway, I'm not an expert (just a provincial hobbyist.) I was doing some optics and radiation physics stuff and happened to pick up a few things (probably very much imperfectly) from listening to others once in a while.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "area" in this context?